# Magento 1.8.1.0 not able to enable cache

Tags: magento, caching

I have an issue with Magento cache

1. when I select all caches in Magento and I click refresh I get this screen:

[url no longer works]

when I then reload the page I get:

[url no longer works]

notice how it is still indicating in red "disabled"? same thing happens when i clear cache.

When I am checking the core_cache_options it looks right, all options has been set to 1 and when disable they are set to 0

Any advise/help is appreciated. I have already deleted /var/* ran all permissions and all other basics.!

Comment: To me this still sounds like a permission problem. What directories does your Magento installation use for tmp files?

Comment: `var/` and its `cache` folder must be writable by the web server process, so depending on SUEXEC, SUPHP or standard DSO implementation of Apache if that's what you're running under, the `var/` folder needs to be 755, 775 or 777. If your web server process runs under a different group or owner than your login, you also may have ownership problems. With permissions/ownership messed up badly enough, Magento will put its cache in the system `/tmp` folder, causing all sorts of weirdness. Get the settings on `var\` correct and delete the cache folder, Magento will recreate with proper permissions.

Comment: this is how I set the permissions:
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

var folder is  in magento-root/var I am not sure where the temp folder is located.

Comment: also both group and owner is set to the same, which is the site login (site owner name)

Answer (score 0):

Permissions need adjusting.

> chmod -R o+w media var && chmod o+w app/etc

Reference: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/installing_magento_via_shell_ssh

Comment: sorry didnt work.. still same issue. I really dont think this is a permissions issue.

Comment: Can you please show the following in the admin:
System/Configuration/Design/Package and /Theme as theme info fields?

Comment: do you mean like a screenshot?